# React: Passing react-icon through an Dictionary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a secondary data file to reduce of code in one component, so I'm using an external `filteringOptionData.ts` file in which I have this structure:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { FaTaxi } from 'react-icons/fa';

export const TaxiIcon = styled(FaTaxi)``;

export default [
  {
    icon: TaxiIcon,
    title: 'general use',
    path: '/ads/general-use/',
  },
  {
    icon: TaxiIcon,
    title: 'taxi',
    path: '/ads/taxi/',
  },
  {
    icon: TaxiIcon,
    title: 'nominal',
    path: '/ads/nominal/',
  },
  {
    icon: TaxiIcon,
    title: 'for electric cars',
    path: '/ads/electric-cars/',
  },
  {
    icon: TaxiIcon,
    title: 'for historic cars',
    path: '/ads/historic-cars/',
  },
];
```

When I'm trying to loop this array and get the icon I receive this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, attrs, componentStyle, shouldForwardProp, foldedComponentIds, styledComponentId, target, withComponent, warnTooManyClasses, toString}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

This is how I'm trying to get the icon:

```
{filterTab.title === 'type' && (
   <FilterTypes>
      {filteringOptionData.map((filter, i) => (
      <FilterOptionWrapper key={i}>
         {filter.icon}
         <FilterOptionTitle>{filter.title}</FilterOptionTitle>
       </FilterOptionWrapper>
       ))}
   </FilterTypes>
)}
```

Comment: try replacing with `<TaxiIcon />` in the object

Comment: 'FaTaxi' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof FaTaxi'?ts(2749)

Answer (score 0):

Just update icon into  like this:

```
export default [
  {
    icon: <TaxiIcon />,
    title: 'general use',
    path: '/ads/general-use/',
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: This does not work @Viet  TS2749: 'FaGlobeEurope' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof FaGlobeEurope'?

Comment: You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|         id: 'filterType',
|         title: "type",
>         icon: />,
|     },
|     {